# Parsing Json with sencha

Tags: json, extjs

I have this format of json

```
[
  {
    "docid": "1",
    "doc_title": "Dato' Dr.",
    "doc_name": "xyz",
    "doc_code": "001",
    "doc_category": "3",
    "doc_subcategory": "",  
    "id": "0"
  },
  {
    "docid": "1",
    "doc_title": "Dr.",
    "doc_name": "ABC",
    "doc_code": "002",
    "doc_category": "4",
    "doc_subcategory": "",  
    "id": "0"
  }
]
```

there are multiple records, I have just included two records

This is my model and parsing code in sencha

```
Ext.define('User', {
                           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                           config: {
                           fields: [
                                    {name: 'docid', type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'doc_title',  type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'doc_name',       type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'doc_code',  type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'doc_category', type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'doc_subcategory',       type: 'string'},   
                                    {name: 'id',       type: 'string'},
                                   ]
                           }
                           });
```

parsing json

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
                                 {
                                     autoLoad: true,
                                     model: "User",

                                     listeners:
                                     {
                                        beforeload: function (store,operation,eOpts)
                                        {
                                        }
                                     },                                          

                                     proxy: {
                                        type: 'ajax',
                                        url : 'http://someurl/doctor/search',

                                        reader: {
                                        type: 'json',
                                        rootProperty: 'users',

                                       }
                                      }                               




                                  });
```

The problem I get only the last record from Json no matter how many records are there in the JSON.

and If I remove the `id` field (Notice the id fields in Json data) it works fine I can be able to have all records parsed.

Why it is doing so? How can I get all the records parsed with sencha?

Comment: Did the answer below fix your problem. If yes, then accept it, otherwise tell us what did not work and what error you got.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the fat that your specifying a `rootProperty` in your proxy but they aren't any in you JSON. From that two choices :

Remove the rootProperty

**or**

Change the structure of your JSON file to something like this :

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "docid": "1",
      "doc_title": "Dato' Dr.",
      "doc_name": "xyz",
      "doc_code": "001",
      "doc_category": "3",
      "doc_subcategory": "",
      "id": "0"
    },
    {
      "docid": "1",
      "doc_title": "Dr.",
      "doc_name": "ABC",
      "doc_code": "002",
      "doc_category": "4",
      "doc_subcategory": "",
      "id": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps